# How can I make (in R) a network map that displays in sequence as a user clicks?

Tags: charts, r

There's this great [network chart that displays sequentially](https://www.hooktheory.com/trends#node=4.5.6&key=C). It looks like this:

[image: awesome image here]

So it's clearly a force network chart... looks like D3 (though I can't tell for sure). How could I build something like that from R? I'm aware there are several network chart packages, but I haven't found any that allow for sequential display based on the onclick event. Is it possible?